# Какого рода слово "евро"?

Tags: морфология

А подскажите, пожалуйста, какого, собственно, рода слово "евро"? Один евро или одно евро? И интересно было бы узнать, почему именно такой род.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 7):

Слово "евро" относится к мужскому роду: один евро. Иноязычные несклоняемые неодушевленные существительные обычно относятся к среднему роду. Но есть и исключения - слова, на род которых влияют различные аналогии. Так, слово салями - женского рода, потому что это колбаса, кольраби, потому что это капуста. В случае с евро, думаю, сработала аналогия с долларом и рублем.

Answer (score 0):

Мужского рода.
Объяснение выше полное и правильное.